# Numpy's bitwise AND behaves differently for matrices Error

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

When computing the bit-wise AND of 2 matrices, sometimes I get a result and sometimes an error, and I don't quite understand why. Here's 2 examples:

The first:

```
a = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]).reshape(3,4)
b = np.array([0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0]).reshape(3,4)
np.bitwise_and(a,b)
```

Gives me the correct result.

While the second:

```
a = np.array(np.zeros(shape=(2,2)))
b = np.array(np.ones(shape=(2,2)))
np.bitwise_and(a,b)
```

Gives me the following error:

`TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`.

Can someone explain to me the difference between my inputs in the first example vs. the second ? And why I'm getting an error?

Comment: `dtype` for `np.zeros` is float.

Comment: What would be the correct dtype then @hpaulj ?

Comment: What's the dtype in the case that works?  What does the function docs say?

Comment: To follow up on what @hpaulj said, think about what a logical `AND` even is. Reading the docs is always a good idea, but this is a matter of basic logic and programming skills.